# Issue with updating JButtons on switching between JTabbedPane tabs

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtabbedpane, changelistener

So the problem I'm having is probably easiest shown in pictures:

This first picture is a shot of the game board
[image]

Each of those squares - 'Plots' - are JButtons.

On clicking one of the JButtons above the Plot display - i.e, 'Buy Produce' - the associated action will happen:

[image]

So far, so good.

But, on switching to either of the other Tabs - 'Commodities' or 'Help' - and switching back to the 'Game' tab, I've only ever been able to have this happen:

[image]

My thinking is that the steps I'm taking to update the Plot display after Buying Produce should work fine to update the display after switching Tabs, but it doesn't.

Here is the code I use to update the display when Buying Produce:

```
buyProduce.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            try {
                buyProduce();
                plot_panel.removeAll();
                createPlots();
                labelStore.get("Cash_Label").setText(game.roundedWorth());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (BankruptException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                        "Bankrupt after attempt to purchase Produce");
            }
        }
    });
```

I've tried doing this with a ChangeListener on the TabbedPane, only to have the Plot display go 'blank' like in the 3rd picture.

```
tabbedPane.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0) {
            plot_panel.removeAll();
            createPlots();
        }

    });
```

However, the display is only 'blank' like this until I perform - through one of the buttons above the display - an action that updates the display.

(If, for example, when the display is 'blank' I 'Buy Produce', everything appears as it should.)

Can anybody here tell, from what I've posted, what is going wrong and where?

I'm happy to post more code if needed, but thought I should try and keep this as neat as possible.

Thanks in advance,
Doug.

EDIT: I didn't want to waste people times with a poor MCVE, so here - http://1drv.ms/1Hx5sA1 - is a link to a compressed folder with all the stuff in it.

If people don't want to trawl through that, then I'll try and switch to a JTable.

Comment: You should `revalidate()` and `repaint()` the `plot_panel` after removing and adding components. But I almost want to say maybe we should look for a different design, but just not enough information to go off of.

Comment: Just tried inserting plot_panel.revalidate() and plot_panel.repaint() after plot_panel.removeAll(); and after createPlots(); (and then both) but no change. Should I paste my (rather large) class in the OP, or somehwere external like PasteBin?

Comment: For better help, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It just wayyyy to little code to go off of.

Comment: Have y considered using a JTable?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I hadn't done, no; My initial plan was to have the Plots 'clickable' - to get their coordinates - and I figured that a JButton (or JLabel) would be the easiest way of doing this. If I cannot get this updating working, then I probably will change to a JTable (Assuming you can display a different picture in each cell?)

Comment: You can display whatever you want in each cell, that's kind of the point

Answer (score 0):

When removing from plot_panel and re-creating, call

```
plot_panel.updateUI();
```

Comment: `updateUI` is probably the worst method you could use and has little to do with making the UI update it's layout and every thing do with making the component reload it's look and feel state, which is incredibly inefficient.  As state by @peeskillet, the OP would probably need to call `revalidate` followed by `repaint`